# MongoDB query for common fields of multiple nested fields

Tags: mongodb

What query is the best to do below?
I've spent quite much time to solve this but did not get a hit.

( I had better to add a little to be clear. I can use nested query 'fieldA.fieldB.fieldC':1, but to my data there are many of 'middle' fields. So I do not want to list them all, and now I'm wondering if there is an option to use wildcards as 'fieldA.*.fieldC':1. )

data:

```
{'name':'A', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_1':'sdf', 'bottom_2':'1263'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_1':'ttt', 'bottom_2':'6565'}}}
{'name':'B', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_1':'ghh', 'bottom_2':'4448'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_1':'gdg', 'bottom_2':'4535'}}}
{'name':'C', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_1':'dfh', 'bottom_2':'7717'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_1':'hewr', 'bottom_2':'2435'}}}
{'name':'D', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_1':'tyr', 'bottom_2':'1211'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_1':'oho', 'bottom_2':'4644'}}}
```

result:

```
{'name':'A', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_2':'1263'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_2':'6565'}}}
{'name':'B', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_2':'4448'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_2':'4535'}}}
{'name':'C', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_2':'7717'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_2':'2435'}}}
{'name':'D', 'top': { 'middle_1': { 'bottom_2':'1211'}, 'middle_2': {'bottom_2':'4644'}}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `db.collection.find()` method's [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#projections) to restrict the fields in the output document.

Comment: @JW Kim : Is this https://mongoplayground.net/p/wl5R8lRMHM5 what you're looking for ?

Comment: @whoami Actually, I don't want to repeat the 'middle' fields, that's the point. e.g, a compact expression like 'top.*.bottom2'.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude what you don't need inside project  `find()`

```
db.yourCollection.find({},
{
  "top.middle_1.bottom_1": 0,
  "top.middle_2.bottom_1": 0
})
```

If you want to use aggregation,

```
db.yourCOllection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "name": 1,
            "top.middle_1.bottom_1": 1,
            "top.middle_2.bottom_2": 1,
        }
    }
])
```

Both are same. `0` to exclude and `1` to include Refer [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Of course, your suggestion is right, but I would like to avoid to list all of the fields. To say, the "middle" fields are more than ten, then I want to find something convenient like wildcards.